# PowerShell / Html - questions

Tags: html, powershell

I am new to Powershell, and I suck at html.

There's a page with a table, and each cell has a ahref link, the value of the link is dynamic, but the link which I want to automate-clicking is always in the first cell.

I know there's cellindex in html/JS, is it usable in PS?

For example, let's say I have this table on a website.

```
<table>

 <tr>
   <td>
  <a href="http://example1.com">
    <div style="height:100%;width:100%">
      hello world1
    </div>
  </a>
</td>

 </tr>

 <tr>
   <td>
  <a href="http://example2.com">
    <div style="height:100%;width:100%">
      hello world2
    </div>
  </a>
</td>
</tr>

 <tr>
   <td>
  <a href="http://example3.com">
    <div style="height:100%;width:100%">
      hello world3
    </div>
  </a>
</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

And I want to make powershell to always click on the first link, the link inside is dynamic though.

Any ideas?  Hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `Invoke-WebRequest` returns a property named `Links` that is a collection of all the hyperlinks on a web page.

For example:

```
$Web = Invoke-webrequest -Uri 'http://wragg.io' $Web.Links | Select innertext,href
```

Returns:

```
innerText                    href
---------                    ----
Mark Wragg                   http://wragg.io
 Twitter                     https://twitter.com/markwragg
 Github                      https://github.com/markwragg 
 LinkedIn                    https://uk.linkedin.com/in/mwragg
```

If the link you want to capture is always the first in this list you could get it by doing:

```
$Web.Links[0].href
```

If it's the second [1], third [2] etc. etc.

I don't think there is an equivalent of "cellindex", although there is a property named `AllElements` that you can access via an array index. E.g if you wanted the second element on the page you could for example do:

```
$Web.AllElements[2]
```

If you need to get to a specific table in the page and then access links inside of that table you'd probably need to iterate through the `AllElements` property until you reached the table you wanted. For example if you know the links were in the third table on the page:

```
$Links = @()
$TableCount = 0

$Web.AllElements | ForEach-Object {

    If ($_.tagname -eq 'table'){ $TableCount++ }

    If ($TableCount -eq 3){

        If ($_.tagname -eq 'a') {
            $Links += $_
        }
    }
}

$Links | Select -First 1
```

Comment: Can I use cellindex? What if there are other tags 'a' above the one I want to select?

Comment: I have overhauled my answer as I forgot about the "Links" property that probably is the simplest solution. I don't think there is an equivalent to cellindex, unless maybe using the AllElements property with an index is similar to what you mean. Each item in `AllElements` has an `innerhtml` and `outerhtml` property so I think you can get the tags around the 'a' tag by accessing `outerhtml`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Mark, one another general question: is there a third party tool or a PS method to know what's the index number of a specific htlm element?

Comment: This would return the name and index number of each tagname in AllElements: `$Web.AllElements.Tagname | ForEach -Begin {$i=0} -Process {"Value:$_ Index:$i"; $i++}`

Comment: Your example is returning me error:  PS C:\Users\Samer> $Web = Invoke-webrequest -Uri 'http://wragg.io' $Web.Links | Select innertext,href
Invoke-WebRequest : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '$null'.
At line:1 char:8
+ $Web = Invoke-webrequest -Uri 'http://wragg.io' $Web.Links | Select i ...
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

Comment: `$Web = Invoke-webrequest -Uri 'wragg.io'` should be `$Web = Invoke-webrequest -Uri 'http://wragg.io'`

Comment: The comment ate the http part:  check the screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/GiI46Ac.jpg

Comment: In your screenshot you are missing a semi-colon before $web.links.

Comment: Your link is working, but the link I am trying is causing a Store popup "You'll need a new app to open this" - ever happened with you?

Comment: I haven't personally deal with that in PowerShell, but you could try adding `-usebasicparsing` as a switch to Invoke-Webrequest as that bypasses Internet Explorer. You still get a `.Links` property returned but you lose AllElements and ParsedHTML as there is no DOM parsing performed.

Comment: Well, everything is working with your link, but not with mine; something is making it difficult in the page I am trying to automate.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the Invoke-webrequest method is working with mark's link but with my page; but I noticed a pattern that may can be used:

I noticed the the following:

```
<table id="row" class="simple">
<thead>
<tr>
<th></th>
<th class="centerjustify">File Name</th>
<th class="centerjustify">File ID</th>
<th class="datetime">Creation Date</th>
<th class="datetime">Upload Date</th>
<th class="centerjustify">Processing Status</th>
<th class="centerjustify">Exceptions</th>
<th class="centerjustify">Unprocessed Count</th>
<th class="centerjustify">Discarded Count</th>
<th class="centerjustify">Rejected Count</th>
<th class="centerjustify">Void Count</th>
<th class="centerjustify">PO Total Count</th>
<th class="centerjustify">PO Total Amount</th>
<th class="centerjustify">CM Total Count</th>
<th class="centerjustify">CM Total Amount</th>
<th class="centerjustify">PO Processed Count</th>
<th class="centerjustify">PO Processed Amount</th>
<th class="centerjustify">CM Processed Count</th>
<th class="centerjustify">CM Processed Amount</th>
<th class="centerjustify">Counts At Upload</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="odd">
<td><input type="radio" disabled="disabled" name="checkedValue" value="12047" /></td>
<td class="leftjustify textColorBlack">
<a href="loadConfirmationDetails.htm?fId=12047">520170123000000_520170123000000_20170327_01.txt</a></td>
<td class="centerjustify textColorBlack">1</td>
<td class="datetime textColorBlack">Mar 27, 2017 0:00</td>
<td class="datetime textColorBlack">Mar 27, 2017 10:33:24 PM +03:00</td>
<td class="centerjustify textColorBlack">
```

The fId part in "loadConfirmationDetails.htm?fId=12047" is dynamic; and it's the last part of the next page;

For example: "https://aaa.xxxxxxx.com/aaa/community/loadConfirmationDetails.htm?fId**=12047**

And table's ID is unique, called "row" - I wonder if I can use a completely another way; other than invoking the webpage, by auto-copying this id info from its source html and concatenate it with the main link?

I am really out of ideas beyond that.